# What is the correct type for a method on a lifetime-parameterized struct?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a struct that contains a reference and so it has a lifetime parameter. I'd like to pass around the function pointer of a method of this struct. Later, I will call that function with an instance of the struct. I ran into snags while trying to store the function pointer, eventually finding this solution:

```
struct Alpha<'a> { a: &'a u8 }

impl<'a> Alpha<'a> {
    fn alpha(&self) -> u8 { *self.a }
}

struct Try1(fn(&Alpha) -> u8);
struct Try2(for<'z> fn(&Alpha<'z>) -> u8);
struct Try3<'z>(fn(&Alpha<'z>) -> u8);

fn main() {
    Try1(Alpha::alpha); // Nope
    Try2(Alpha::alpha); // Nope
    Try3(Alpha::alpha);
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work for my real case because I want to implement a trait that has its own notion of lifetimes:

```
trait Zippy {
    fn greet<'a>(&self, &Alpha<'a>);
}

impl<'z> Zippy for Try3<'z> {
    fn greet<'a>(&self, a: &Alpha<'a>) { println!("Hello, {}", self.0(a)) }
}
```

Produces the error:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `&Alpha<'z>`,
    found `&Alpha<'a>`
```

I feel that I shouldn't need to tie the lifetime of my struct `Try3` to the lifetime of the parameter of the function pointer, but the compiler must be seeing something I'm not.

Comment: As a work around, you can either define a function `fn hack(a: &Alpha) -> u8 { Alpha::alpha(a) }` or use `mem::transmute` to get a suitable value for `Try1` or `Try2`.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner If you add the first workaround as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the function `alpha` implemented on the struct `Alpha` effectively takes the struct's lifetime as a parameter, despite not actually using it. This is a limitation of the syntax for defining methods on structs with lifetimes. So even though it is possible to take a pointer to it as a `for<'z> fn(&Alpha<'z>) -> u8`, it is not possible to treat it as a `fn(&Alpha) -> u8`, even though the definition suggests this should be possible.

This can be worked around by defining a function that invokes the method and take a pointer to it instead:

```
fn workaround(a: &Alpha) -> u8 { Alpha::alpha(a) }
Try1(workaround);
```

In fact, it may be better to do it the other way around, with the definition in the function and the method invoking the function. Then when the function is invoked through a `fn(&Alpha) -> u8` pointer a second jump won't be necessary into the method, and calls to the method can be inlined as calls to the function.